# Sort all monthly incomes and group by year

Tags: mysql

I want to show all my monthly incomes and group them yearly, like in the picture below.
The query is like

```
SELECT 
monthname(date_added) as monthno,
year(date_added) as year,
SUM(amount) as amounts 
FROM incomes GROUP BY year ORDER BY monthno
```

but it groups yearly and hides months of the year:

[image]

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqs1j.png)

Comment: Please [edit} your desired results into the question (as formatted text, instead of an image)

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS monthno
     , SUM(amount) AS monthsum
  FROM incomes 
 GROUP BY monthno 
 ORDER BY monthno
;
```

More [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) are available for getting a text version of the date.

Comment: thanks danblack it helped me a lot, and also thanks for the link you provided.

Comment: @JawadAlizada - Note that this will sum all data from January of any year, all data from February of any year, etc. It does appear to be what you're asking for at this time, but I wanted to be sure you were clear about this.